# API Key Kudan AR not valid

Tags: kudan

When i use the following code in my Appdelegate class in xcode it should normally let me access the API from KudanAR but it doesn't let me it says the key is invalid when this is the key I got from their site does anyone have a valid key?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[ARAPIKey sharedInstance] setAPIKey:@"GAWQE-F9AQU-2G87F-8HKED-Q7BTG-TY29G-RV85A-XN3ZP-A9KGM-E8LB6-VC2XW-VTKAK-ANJLG-2P8NX-UZMAH-Q"];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the key you are trying to use is for the `eu.kudan.ar` bundleID.

If the AR is failing to start because of an `invalid api key`, that would mean that you haven't entered the matching bundleID into your app's plist.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it was because I hadn't used the correct bundle id I found out last night thrue Kudan's support services

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. My XCode says that I cannot use this bundleID (and any of those here https://wiki.kudan.eu/Development_License_Keys) and seems to be working only with a new unique one which does not match the license ID. Any ideas how to solve that?